# MicroPython ESP32 CanBus

Tags: can-bus, micropython

Good morning, I've been wanting to use the `CAN` module from the `machine` library on an ESP32 based board, unfortunatelly, as I thought, I'm getting an error when trying to import it

```py
>>> from machine import CAN
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CAN'
```

Is there any way to enable the `CAN` module on an ESP32 board? I'm following [this example](https://docs.pycom.io/firmwareapi/pycom/machine/can/) and it's written:

> [...] The ESP32 has a built-in CAN controller, but the transceiver needs to be added externally. [...]

It states that it *should* be possible to use the module on an ESP32 board.

Comment: If it's just missing the transceiver but got a controller, then that's easy enough to fix. I'm sure there's premade boards for that - or in case you know basic soldering, you can very easily build one yourself.

Answer (score 1):

According to the generic micropython documentation, it seems to have CAN [only on the pyboard](http://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/pyb.CAN.html).

The documentation you reference is specific to the micropython firmware for pycom boards.

So whether a board does or does not support the CAN bus will depend on the hardware and firmware it comes with.

Comment: I have a custom [ESP32 board](https://www.tindie.com/products/voltlog/canlite-esp32-can-development-board/) it does have a CAN BUS receiver & transmitter, is it possible to use the CAN BUS functionality with micropython?

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński Looking at the MicroPython source code, the STM32 port seems to have support for the CAN bus while the ESP32 port hasn't. Someone would have to make a port for this specific board. (There is no `CANLITE` in `micropython/ports/esp32/boards/`.)

Comment: I guess you'd be looking at porting the [CAN module from Pycom](https://github.com/pycom/pycom-micropython-sigfox/tree/Dev/esp32/can) to your own board.

Comment: There is also this port of an older pycom firmware for esp32 -- https://github.com/Tbruno25/pycom-esp32-universal